# How to get disabled test cases count in jenkins result?

Tags: selenium, jenkins, testng, jenkins-plugins

I have suppose 10 test cases in test suite in which 2 test cases are disabled.I want to get those two test cases in test result of jenkins job like pass = 7 ,fail = 1 and disabled/notrun= 2.

Comment: Do you just want to get it in logs or in testng plugin of jenkins?

Comment: Want in testNG plugin of jenkins.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default, TestNG generates report for your test suite and you may refer to index.html file under the test-output folder. If you click on "Ignored Methods" hyperlink, it will show you all the ignored test cases and its class name and count of ignored methods.

All test cases annotated with @Test(enabled = false) will be showing in "Ignored Methods" link.

I have attached a sample image. Refer below.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the help.I tried it in my local eclipce and able to see skipped test cases.But if i run this on jenkins and anyhow some test cases skipped because of another reason than that test cases will be shown in test result if it is not disabled.Than how can we get actual skipped and disabled test cases.Any idea.

Comment: http://testng.org/javadocs/org/testng/TestListenerAdapter.html -- Please check  this class

Answer (score 0):

If your test generates JUnit XML reports, you can use the JUnit plugin to parse these reports after the build (as a post-build action). Then, you can go into your build and click 'Test Result'. You should see a breakdown of how the execution went (including passed, failed, and skipped tests).

Comment: Yes we can saw pass fail and skipped test count but is there any way to get test cases which are disabled in report..?